# R Package "DistributionUtils" installation error

Tags: r, install.packages

I try to install the "DistributionUtils" package (on a Mac) via

```
install.packages("DistributionUtils")
```

I am asked whether I want to install these from sources. I answer 'Yes' (notice: when answering 'no', the code does not proceed with the installation). Then, the following error occurs (see full code below):

`make: *** [IncompleteBessel.o] Error 1
    ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘DistributionUtils’`

**Two questions:**

- (Q1) Why does the error occur?
- (Q2) How can I install the package alternatively?

Any help is appreciated. Please find below the full execution code:

```
install.packages("DistributionUtils")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:
  ‘DistributionUtils’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
installing the source package ‘DistributionUtils’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/DistributionUtils_0.6-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 41231 bytes (40 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 40 KB

* installing *source* package ‘DistributionUtils’ ...
** package ‘DistributionUtils’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gfortran  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c IncompleteBessel.f -o IncompleteBessel.o
make: gfortran: No such file or directory
make: *** [IncompleteBessel.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘DistributionUtils’
* removing    ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/DistributionUtils’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘DistributionUtils’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
       ‘/private/var/folders/pp/nll33qgs6w52y4bkhjdxvvdh0000gn/T/RtmpTZoRq5/downloaded_packages’
```

–––––––––––––––––––––––

**EDIT**: Following Konard Rudolph's suggestions, I installed GCC via Homebrew. However, it still does not work and I receive now thew following error:

```
install.packages("DistributionUtils")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘DistributionUtils’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
installing the source package ‘DistributionUtils’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/DistributionUtils_0.6-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 41231 bytes (40 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 40 KB

* installing *source* package ‘DistributionUtils’ ...
** package ‘DistributionUtils’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gfortran  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c IncompleteBessel.f -o IncompleteBessel.o
IncompleteBessel.f:117:36:

  117 |       subroutine GNUM(n,x,y,nu,Am,An,nmax,Cnp,GM,GN)
      |                                    1
Warning: Unused dummy argument 'an' at (1) [-Wunused-dummy-argument]
IncompleteBessel.f:34:34:

   34 |       double precision BI(0:numax),BK(0:numax)
      |                                  1
Warning: Unused variable 'bi' declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
IncompleteBessel.f:34:46:

   34 |       double precision BI(0:numax),BK(0:numax)
      |                                              1
Warning: Unused variable 'bk' declared at (1) [-Wunused-variable]
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c init.c -o init.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o DistributionUtils.so IncompleteBessel.o init.o -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [DistributionUtils.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘DistributionUtils’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/DistributionUtils’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘DistributionUtils’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/pp/nll33qgs6w52y4bkhjdxvvdh0000gn/T/RtmpA1L5oK/downloaded_packages’
```

Answer (score 1):

> (Q1) Why does the error occur?

As the error message says, the error occurs because you haven’t got the GNU Fortran compiler (`gfortran`) installed. The installation warned you that this might be required when installing from source:

> Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:
>     ‘DistributionUtils’

> (Q2) How can I install the package alternatively?

You need to install the package’s external dependencies. In other words, you need to install GCC, of which `gfortran` is a part. The easiest way of doing this is [via Homebrew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/139979/2392).

Comment: Many thanks – it still does not seem to work after installing GCC via Homebrew and restart of the system (see edited question above). Why does it still not work? What else has to be done?